# Change the Editor Page for a Google Optimize experiment?

Tags: google-optimize

I have set up an Experiment and have it working locally. I have subsequently deployed the site to a staging domain and now need to be able to preview/debug it there as well, however I can find no way to change what Google calls the 'Editor Page' URL which you input when creating a new Experiment and which is used for Debugging and Previewing variants. Mine is set to a URL on my local machine, but now I need to change it to a URL on our staging server.

**How can I update the Editor Page URL?**

Note I'm not talking about URL targeting here. I'm targeting using regex which doesn't care about the domain.